# How to find disk usage per-user in Linux?

Tags: linux, diskspace

Given a directory `d` and a list of users, I want to find disk space used by each user in directory `d`.I cannot install any utility as it's a production environment so need a result using standard LINUX command(s)

Answer (score 3):

you mean just a du -sh of /home/ ?

```
du -sh /home/*
1.2G    /home/user001
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The following shell script will get the disk usage, in human readable form (`-h`), sort the results and deliver the top 10 values:

```
sudo du -Sh | sort -rh | head -10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try - 
du -shc /home/* 
 
Where, 
 
s :- display total size of a file or total size of all files in a directory.
 
h :- human readable format.
 
c :- display a total size usage at the end of result.